# Special Characters Don't Display Correctly in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, character-encoding

I have a Laravel application on my local machine, all strings show well.
I pass the application to another pc, open a port and now I can access remotely but the `the words with special character don't show`.

For example, to print user auth name I have this

```
<span>
    <a href="edit-user">
        {{ Auth::user()->name }}
    </a>
</span>
```

The name is `John Mão` and don't show but if I change the HTML to

```
<span>
    <a href="edit-user">
        <?php echo Auth::user()->name ?>
    </a>
</span>
```

It displays like this: `John M�o`.

In my header, I have the tag `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

I also check if database collection is the same(`utf8_general_ci`) then local machine and if the records show well in the tables it's ok.

I don't know if it could be related to the fact that I use 2 databases, one myself and another SQL with a sqlsrv driver. But the hidden character came from the MySQL database.

Could the problem be on the server where I put the application?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `{!! !!}` insead of `{{ }}` ?

Comment: Don't work @JeuneGuerrier

Comment: @JeuneGuerrier Do you have any knowledge regarding security? Please include a very obvious warning of the enormous danger of implementing this solution! Echoing unescaped user supplied data is just asking for an xss attack!

Comment: check the character encoding of your actual php files

Comment: In phpinfo default_charset parameter is set UTF-8 @delboy1978uk

Comment: that's the encoding of the generated html. what are the php files encoding set to in your ide/text editor?

Comment: In IDE is UTF-8 too @delboy1978uk